# consolidating data from a json in a new array and drawing shapes with it using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a new array from this json

```
http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/a7hj-s5px.json
```

where I am storing the zip code and how many times the zip code is showing up in the dataset.

it has other information such as what type of noise and as such which I will deal with later.

Here is what I doing:
Checking how many unique zip codes we have in the dataset by doing this

```
var zipValue = [];
var zipFrequency = [];

var map = d3.map();
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        var zipCount = map.get(d.incident_zip);
        map.set(d.incident_zip, zipCount === undefined ? 1 : ++zipCount);
    });

    //storing the mapped values in an array
    zipValue = map.keys(map);
    zipFrequency = map.values(map);


var hScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(newArray, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
        .range([7, 70]);
```

and finally trying to pass the hScale as a parameter to the shape.

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/rYXbG/15/

Where exactly I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the console? I checked your fiddle and you have an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'hScale'`

And, it seems like it's been caused by:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(newArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (k++) + 2)
    .attr("y", 125)
    .attr("width", 2)
    .attr("height", function (d, i) {return d.hScale(d[1]);});
```

The last line should just be `return hscale(d[1]);` instead of `d.hscale`.

Comment: @icanc--yes i did see that error. But couldnt figure out why. Thatnks for the correction. It worked